# Japanese file name is storing in garbage characters

Tags: java, linux, utf-8, debian

I have a file with Japanese characters in its name, which I am uploading from windows to Debian (Linux) using this line of code:

```
file.write( new File( "/storing/path/", "ネットワーキング.xml" ) );
```

When I check the file through command prompt in Debian (Linux), it is stored as

```
"???????????.xml"
```

I tried different approaches but nothing works till now -

1) using `BufferedReader`:

```
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader( file.getStream() , "UTF-8") );

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(
                        new File( "/storing/path/", "ネットワーキング.xml" )), "UTF-8"));
```

2) followed this link http://okomestudio.net/biboroku/?p=1834
 to try to add locale in Debian:

```
a) $ sudo aptitude install locales im-config
b) $ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales -> added en_US.UTF-8 and ja_JP.UTF-8
c) Set the default locale for the system to en_US.UTF-8. 
d) Install some Japanese fonts:
e) $ sudo aptitude install ttf-kochi-mincho ttf-kochi-gothic ttf-sazanami-mincho
```

Then tried with only ja_JP.UTF-8 locale

What am I doing wrong, and where?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First figure out if the problem is with the command prompt or your program -- can you create and display a file with japanese characters directly from the command prompt? Or are there already other files which are displayed correctly?

Comment: The encoding specified for input/output stream does not affect the file name. Are your sure your source file encoding is UTF8 and the compiler uses the same encoding? You can avoid problems with that if you use unicode escape syntax instead: `"\u30cd\u30c3\u30c8\u30ef\u30fc\u30ad\u30f3\u30b0.xml"`

Comment: yes mata, file is a xml file and i am using
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
and file name is dynamically coming it can be anything

Comment: Hi Adrian, 
I tried to upload file via bitwise (SSH client) than it display character right but when i try to list that file on Debian console it is showing garbage characters( file name).
It can be my console problem too but I am not sure.

Comment: what is the filesystem you writing to?

Comment: Linux filesystem isn't relevant, to them the filename is just a list of bytes. At your linux prompt type "locale charmap" -- you want this to be UTF-8. How are you getting your file from Windows to Linux ?

Comment: hi user3710044
 i am getting UTF-8 and i am getting correct file name and file path till point i am writing it to the linux system but just after creating file, File name is garbage